# Split list to lists based on condition in one line

Tags: python, list, filter

I have a list that I want to split by condition:

```
l = [1,2,3,7,8,9,4]
```

to

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4] , l2 = [7,8,9]
```

Based on the condition: x > 5.
The code is:

```
l1 = []
l2 = []
for x in l:
    if x > 5:
       l1.append(x)
    else:
       l2.append(x)
```

Is there a more pythonic/faster way to do it?

Comment: @Gsk, they just edited it...

Comment: @Gsk, its true, I think is too late, I should go to sleep x_x

Comment: Since this question relates partially to performance, I've added a NumPy-based duplicate.

Comment: "pythonic" mostly means "as simple, obvious and readable as possible", so your current code is actually the most pythonic solution here.